# styles and print and output

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, output

I know I can use styles to change how the result of [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) looks. But I have a case where I use [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) to display some informational output and also some result:

```
a=2;
b=3;
c=a+b;
Print["Variable a = ", a]; (* this I want with font size 12, or let's say Style1 *)
Print["Variable b = ", b]; (* this I want with font size 12, or let's say Style1 *)
Print["The result: a + b = ", c]; (* this I want with font size 16 with background color and in bold and probably different font, or let's say Style2 *)
```

The whole point of this is that I need the result printed after some text (i.e. in the same line). I know there are some solutions but all of them are enormously complicated. [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) is simple and quick. But I need to distinguish the style of those prints. I can assign different styles manually to the results (Style2) but I have to redo it after each evaluation of the notebook.

### Update

To give exact code:

```
p0 = Quantity[10^5, "Pascals"];
rE = Quantity[6378*10^3, "Meters"];
gE = Quantity[9.81, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2];
m = UnitConvert[(p0*4*π*rE^2)/gE, "SIBase"];
Print["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(0\)]\) = ", p0];
Print["R = ", rE];
Print["g = ", gE];
Print["Mass of the atmosphere is: ", m];
```

If I do what @MarcoB suggested in his comment, it looks:

```
styleRes = 
  Style[#, FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Bold, 
    Background -> LightRed] &;
p0 = Quantity[10^5, "Pascals"];
rE = Quantity[6378*10^3, "Meters"];
gE = Quantity[9.81, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2];
m = UnitConvert[(p0*4*π*rE^2)/gE, "SIBase"];
Print["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(0\)]\) = ", p0];
Print["R = ", rE];
Print["g = ", gE];
Print[styleRes@StringJoin["Mass of the atmosphere is: ", ToString@m]];
```

And you can see the horror of caused by [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html). This is why I preferred to stick with `Print["text",expression]` because that gets the formating absolutely right, [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) messes everything up.

If there is a way to make a "bullet proof" `ToString` without spending hours to just write the code, I am all ears. I know, I could use `ToString[expr,TraditionalForm]` but I simply do not trust it to render results the same as *Mathematica* renders the output (e.g. [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) does not make space between thousands and I frankly have no idea what other caveats it has).

Comment: Yes, but unsure how to apply it to whole Print.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this will fit your needs:

```
myPrint[args__, {style__}] := Print[Row[{args}, BaseStyle -> {style}]]
```

---

```
myPrint["Mass of the atmosphere is: ", m, 
    {FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Bold, Background -> LightRed}]

myPrint["Mass of the atmosphere is: ", m, {"Section"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

define your styles beforehand,

```
style1 = Style[#, 12] &;
style2 = Style[#, 24, Blue, Background -> Pink] &;
```

and then just use them quickly and easily,

```
Print["Variable a = ", style1@a];
Print["Variable b = ", style1@b];
Print["The result: a + b = ", style2@c];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I would like the whole line with that style, i.e. the whole printout of a single print command be formatted, not just the expression.

Comment: @leosenko ... then you may want to join the expressions in a single string, to which you can apply your style, within the `Print` command. For instance: `Print[style2@StringJoin["The result: a + b = ", ToString@c]];`

Comment: Is there any way to avoid `ToString`? See my updated question.