# change the output of Print command in Article style

Tags: output-formatting

I am working with the Article-style.
How can I change globally the output of `Print` command?

For example typing

```
x=3;
Print["x", x]
```

will produce the same output with

```
x = 3;
Print[Style["x=", Red], x]
```

without the need to specify the `Style`.

Thanks.

**EDIT 2**

I apologize for the inconvenience. I thought that I could get what I want with a minimal example. I should have been more specific from the very beginning.

In reality I have my definitions (below is just a part).

```
ruls = {Nc0 -> 35.794, Nc1 -> 509.74, Ns0 -> 18.275, 
   Ns1 -> 27.971, β -> 0.8, m -> 0.0304, τ -> 1.4503, 
   zp0 -> 1000, zp1 -> 1, 
       α -> 5.3/10^3, χ -> 1., Tref -> 298.15, 
   C1 -> 45.685, C2 -> 245.06, η0 -> 0.2343, 
   Tinit -> 294.75, Δt -> 0.003}; 
elstrain = {0.00005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
Δelstrain = {0.00005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 
Δstrain = {0.00005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 

equivStrainRate = 
  Sqrt[2/3 Δstrain.Δstrain]/\
Δt /. ruls;
aT[T_] := 10^(-C1 (T - Tref)/(C2 + (T - Tref)));
aTinit = aT[Tinit] /. ruls;
λ = aT[Tinit] equivStrainRate /. ruls;
η = η0 /. ruls;
DaTDT = D[aT[T], T] /. T -> Tinit /. ruls;
DλDT = DaTDT equivStrainRate;

Print[Style["Values of Quantities\n", Blue, 
  Bold], "equivStrainRate=", equivStrainRate, "\n", \
"equivStrainRateStar=", equivStrainRateStar, "\n", "aT=", aTinit, "\n\
", "\[Lambda]=", \[Lambda], "\n", "\[Eta]=", \[Eta], "\n", "DaTDT=", \
DaTDT, "\n", "D\[Lambda]DT=", D\[Lambda]DT]
```

[image]

I want the `equivStrainRate=`, `equivStrainRateStar=`, etc in above output to appear Red.

Comment: Ok! I will redit it.

Comment: Thanks. What Article style has to do with the problem?

Comment: @Kuba: I wanted to clarify the I don't use the Default style. I am not sure if this affects really the question.

Comment: So you want to confine it to a single stylesheet?

Comment: So why not creating `myPrint[name_, rest___]:=Print[Style[name<>"=", Red], rest]` like in [104839](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104839/5478)

Comment: @Kuba. Thanks! How can I modify the function in the case of, e.g., `x = 3; y = 5; z = x + y;
Print[Style["x=", Red], x, Style["\ny=", Red], y, Style["\nz=", Red],
  z]`

Comment: @dimitris, just use `myPrint[args__] := Print[Row[{args}, BaseStyle -> {Red}]];  myPrint["x=", x, "\ny=", y, "\nz=", z]`

Comment: @JasonB: It just to demonstrate what output I want to obtain:-)!

Comment: myPrint[x__] := (Print[Style[# <> " = ", Red], #2] & @@@ 
     Partition[{x}, 2];) ?

Comment: @Kuba and @ JasonB. Thanks for your interest. I redited the question. I thought I could receive an answer just by giving a minimal example. I was blatantly wrong:-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myPrint[lbl_, x__] := Print@Grid[
   Join[{{Style[lbl, Blue], SpanFromLeft}}, 
    Partition[Riffle[{x}, "=", {2, -2, 3}], 3]],
   ItemStyle -> {{{Red}, {Red}, {}}, {}}
   ]

myPrint["title", "x", 1, "y", 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This hardly seems like a shortcut to just typing it all out longhand, but try this

```
names = {"equivStrainRate", "equivStrainRateStar", "aT", "λ", 
   "η", "DaTDT", "DλDT"};
vals = {equivStrainRate, equivStrainRateStar, 
   aTinit, λ, η, DaTDT, DλDT};
Grid[Transpose[
   {Style[#, Red] & /@ names, ConstantArray[Style["=", Red], 7], 
    vals}]~Prepend~{Style["Values of Quantities", Blue, Bold], 
   SpanFromLeft}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very close but I guess I am very bizarre! I want the very name, e.g., equivStrainRate= in Red; but not the value of the variable itself (here 0.0136083).